# How do you find what program is installing third-party Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome, security, google-chrome-extensions, malware

When I added a new profile to my Chrome installation I get the alert message in the top-right *New extension added (Web Safety)*

[image]

Clicking on the alert message opens a message saying that another program on my system had added it.

[image]

Digging around it seems like an extension that I don't want on Chrome.

I was able to remove the extension...

[image]

...which launched a page to a farewell message with an Adaware webcompannion.com address.

[image]

I do not have Web Companion by Adaware installed on my computer so I assume that another program I have installed is acting on their behalf.

How do I find the program that is automatically installing this Chrome extension so that I can uninstall it?

Comment: Not an answer, but Adaware is an antivirus, anti-spyware company that makes multiple products. However, the likely culprit probably has Adaware in the title of the product. So I would begin with your installed program files, looking specifically for anti-malware software and then move on to Chrome extensions such as ad blocking software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a new chrome profile so that the notifications of the extension being added are there.

Then go to chrome://extensions and then turn on developer mode at the top
copy and paste the extension ID (so it could be something like lmjegmlicamnimmfhcmpkclmigmmcbeh)

Search in the ENTIRE Local Disk (C:) that ID. It may take a while.
Then go to the Registry Editor and go to *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE > Google > Chrome > Extensions* and then delete that file.
That should remove the extension for you.

If it doesn't, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and search that extension ID. Delete every file that has that name, you may need to search multiple times.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Worked. The disk search is not necessary. Only the registry part is needed.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is going to be to run the installers for everything that you have installed on your system once again and see which of them offers to install that extension somewhere within the installation process.

Not all programs that install unwanted extensions like this are inherently untrustworthy, but I can totally understand your desire for revenge on a program that would do something like this.